# Query difference between TimeField and Current Datetime in Django

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to pick values from Django a model where the difference between `validity` field, which is a `DateTimeField`, and the current time should be lesser than 10 minutes.

For that I tried:

```
now = datetime.datetime.now()
now_plus_10 = now + datetime.timedelta(minutes = 10)
slots_bookings = Table.objects.filter(validity__lte=now_plus_10)
```

However, this will always give me a any value that's lesser than 10 minutes from now which can include timestamps from even more than the 10 minute window.

I'm trying to figure if there's a way I can get the fields where

```
current_time - validity <= 10 minutes
```

How do I go about this?

Comment: `validity__gte=now_plus_10`

Answer (score 0):

```
now = datetime.datetime.now()
delta = datetime.timedelta(minutes=10)
now_plus_10 = now + delta
now_minus_10 = now - delta
Tables.objects.filter(validity__gte=now_minus_10, validity__lte=now_plus_10)
```

You may use `django.utils.timezone.now` instead of `datetime.datetime.now` if you use timezones.